# Is it possible to stay in Ireland with a work visa provided by another EEA country?

Tags: working-visas, ireland, europe

Hypothetically, if one were working in Ireland and didn't have time for the disorganized Irish government to sort out a working visa to permit full time work, would a working visa from another EEA country be a possible avenue?

In other words, if a company has subsidiaries in EEA countries other than Ireland could it allow an employee to work in Ireland, even if "remotely working" from that country?

Comment: Don't have full facts so this is just a comment, but unless that other country is the UK you won't even get a travel-visa (as a byproduct of your work visa) to Ireland, as it's not part of the Schengen area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Visas from other countries are not valid for Ireland (with the exception of certain UK visitors' visas issued under the British Irish visa scheme, but these do not permit work in either country).